# QGIS export JPEG with a scale

Tags: qgis, export

I use Export function to JEPG because I have to use it for printing a great map.
I would like to have a scale appearing somewhere on this JPEG. Is did not find to do this with the export function.
IS it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check the available options under View-Decorations: https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/map_views/map_view.html#decorations.

Comment: Great, I never saw these options before ....